Error while using TurboVNC in Intel dev cloud one api Rendering Toolkit
I am trying to connect to Intel Dev cloud through SSh client (https://devcloud.intel.com/oneapi/get_started/renderingToolkitSamples/). I've completed all the steps mentioned in the aritcle but at the end at TurboVNC part it just throws the error "Connection refused". And in the terminal it also shows connection refused. I tried asking in intel's forums and customer support still no fix for the issue. These are the images from the point of issue.](https://i.sstatic.net/gcbYV.png)
I tried the forums (https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-DevCloud/turbovnc-connection-failed/td-p/1414092) and (https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-DevCloud/Connection-closed-attempt-to-reconnect-yes-no/td-p/1570755) and many others still no solution.

hi you can connect to the vm via ngrok and i just tried it and connected the server. install ngrok in your server and it should above 3.0 version. create account in ngrok and copy auth token from ngrok and add ngrok auth token in the server by this code
./ngrok authtoken your-authtoken 

and generete otp from this code
./opt/TurboVNC/bin/vncserver -otp

so it can be entered later.
./ngrok tcp 5901

you will get address like this
tcp://1.tcp.ngrok.io:XXXXX
  ex(12345)

enter this 1.tcp.ngrok.io:XXXXX
in any vnc viewer it will ask for you password enter it and thats it. if you have any problem doing ask help for chatgpt it will help you.
